# Delete record using jquery ajax but table is loaded again

Tags: php, jquery

I am deleting records using jQuery and Ajax. The code I wrote deletes a record but the HTML table is loaded again, which means the page refreshes which I want to avoid.

Here is my code:

**comment.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function loadList(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "load_list.php",
            cache: false,
            success : function(html){
                $(".name_list").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
    loadList();

    $("#Submit").click(function() {
        if($(":text").val().length==0)
            {
               // $(this).next().html("Field needs filling");
               $(":text").after('<span class="errorkeyup">Field cannot be empty</span>');
                //return false;
                success = false;
            }
            else
            {
                var name=$("#name").val();
                var message=$("#message").val();
                $.ajax({
                  type:"post",
                   url:"save_list.php",
                   data:"name="+name+"&message="+message,                             
                  success:function(data){
                 loadList();                                
                 } 
                }); 
                return false;
            }
    });
    $(".delete_button").on("click", function(){
        //this deletes the row clicked on with an alert and then reloads the list
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        /*var x=window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
        if (x==true){*/
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete.php",
                data: "id="+ id,
                success: function(){
                    loadList();
                }
            });
       // }
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="form">

<form method="post" name="form" action="">
<div id="content">
 Name :    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
               </br>
               Message : <input type="text" name="message" id="message" />
               </br>
               </div>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="Submit">

</form>
</div>
<div class="name_list"></div>

</body>
```

**loadlist.php**

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$sqlnew = 'Select * from login order by id ASC';
    $res = mysql_query($sqlnew);
    echo'<table border="1">';
    echo'<tr>';
    echo'<td>SrNo.</td>';
    echo '<td>Name:</td>';
    echo '<td>Message:</td>';
    echo '<td>Delete</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
    $i=1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo'<td>'.$i.'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$row['username'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['message'].'</td>';
        echo"<td>
          <a id='".$row['id']."' href=delete.php?id=".$row['id']."&type=Delete class=delete_button>Delete</a></td>";
        echo"<td>
          <a id='".$row['id']."' href=comment.php?id=".$row['id']."&type=edit class=edit_button>Edit</a></td>";         
        echo '</tr>';
        $i++;

    }
    echo'</table>';

?>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

  if(isset($_REQUEST["id"]))
  {
  $cmd=mysql_query("delete from login where id=" .$_REQUEST["id"] .";");
   header("location: comment.php");
  }

?>
```

Comment: Security vulnerabilities exist in this code.

Comment: `header(location...)` redirects the page

Comment: What do you want to happen on the page when you submit? Do you want it to reload the table (to show that the record has been deleted)? What is happening wrong now, is the whole page reloading?

Comment: You still have an `href` attribute on your `a.delete_button`. It looks like your click event is firing to delete the record via an ajax call and is then refreshing with a `delete.php?id=".$row['id']."&type=Delete` call. I could be wrong, but I would try changing it to `href='#'`

Comment: @HugoDozois If I remove header(location...) then page is sent to delete.php I want when delete link is clicked particular row should be removed but whole table is reloaded then change is showed

Comment: need to prevent default submit for all conditions. Only returning `false` for one condition right now

Answer (score 0):

When you do the `$.ajax()` call for `$('.delete_button')`, you shouldn't call your `loadList()` function there because that is what reloads the table, instead you should just remove the one entry that's deleted from the table.

Perhaps you can remove it with something similar to this, placed inside the delete button success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "delete.php",
    data: "id="+ id,
    success: function()
    {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

  if(isset($_REQUEST["id"]))
  {
  $cmd=mysql_query("delete from login where id=" .$_REQUEST["id"] .";");
   header("location: comment.php");
  }

?>
```

in this code remove line

```
header("location: comment.php");
```

Final code would be,

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

  if(isset($_REQUEST["id"]))
  {
   $cmd=mysql_query("delete from login where id=" .$_REQUEST["id"] .";");
   echo '1';
  } else {
   echo '0';
  }

  exit;
?>
```

In delete function, after executing delete query, you need to echo '1' or '0'. Lets say echo '1'; when deleted successfully and echo '0' when delete not succeed. So based on 1 or 0 you can remove those deleted row from table by ,

$(".delete_button").on("click", function(){
        //this deletes the row clicked on with an alert and then reloads the list
        var obj = $(this);
        var id = obj.attr("id");

```
    /*var x=window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
    if (x==true){*/
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete.php",
            data: "id="+ id,
            success: function(response){
                if(response == '1') {
                      obj.parent.remove();
                }
            }
        });
   // }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution when I click delete it takes me to delete.php and display 1 it does not stay  on comment.php page If I remove delete.php from href tag it link does not works